# Unhide div from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with the brown branches like the picture and I need to hide it and, when a button is clicked, unhide from bottom to top, as if it have a mask.
I can't show it with a bottom-up slide (in jquery for example) because the top has the leafs and stuff, so the best idea I've come with is to unhide with some kind of mask.

Right now I have this:

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
        $('#branchmain').show('slide', {direction: 'down'}, 1000);
  });
```

```css
#branchmain {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IV2C28A.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:none;
    width: 114px;
    height: 307px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div id="branchmain"></div>
```

How could I apply a mask to the div and unhide it from bottom to top? I don't want it to move from bottom to top, but to reveal it. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Thats a sad story.... Maybe share your code and turn your story into a question...

Comment: Can you share ur current code ?

Comment: There could be many ways to go about this. Too broad to be answered and very opinion based. Please include a code example of your _specific problem_ as well as any attempts you may have tried.

Comment: I've added code, sorry for the initial question.

Comment: So you don't hany question???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if you use the 'blind' effect instead of 'slide'.

In case you need to reveal the tree in front of some other image, use layered divs.

```js
$('.button').click(function () {
        $('#branchmain').show('blind', {direction: 'down'}, 1000);
  });
```

```css
#branchmain {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/IV2C28A.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:none;
    width: 114px;
    height: 307px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Click me!</div>
<div id="branchmain"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a combination of a SVG clipping mask and CSS animation to animate the fade up approach.
Please note I've made the CSS run infinitely and tweaked some settings purely for the demo, I'm surely you'll want to do things slightly differently. But as a proof of concept it works perfectly in my opinion:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <img class="clipped" src="http://i.imgur.com/IV2C28A.png" />  
  <svg width="100px" height="400px">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipping">
        <rect width="100" height="300"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: inherit;
    left: 0;
  }
  img.clipped {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
    z-index: 100;
  }

  div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 410px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  div.clipped {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping);
    z-index: 100;
  /*  opacity: 0;*/
  }
  svg rect {
    animation: move-mask infinite running 4s;
  }
  @keyframes move-mask {
  0%, 100% {transform: translateY(0)}
  50% {transform: translateY(600px)}
  }
```

Demo / Codepen here:

http://codepen.io/mrwigster/pen/eJNBBK

Answer (score 1):

You can position one `div` (with a `background-image`) over the top of another and incrementally reduce the `max-height` of the uppermost `div`:

```js
function witherTree() {
var treeWithLeaves = document.getElementsByClassName('tree-with-leaves')[0];
var treeWithoutLeaves = document.getElementsByClassName('tree-without-leaves')[0];
var treeWithLeavesHeight = treeWithoutLeaves.clientHeight;
treeWithLeaves.style.maxHeight = treeWithLeavesHeight + 'px';

var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
treeWithLeaves.style.maxHeight = (treeWithLeavesHeight - i) + 'px';
i++;
},20);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',witherTree,false);
```

```css
body {
margin: 25px 0 0 50px;
}

.tree-with-leaves, .tree-without-leaves {
width: 125px;
height: 236px;
}

.tree-with-leaves {
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/a140q.png');
}

.tree-without-leaves  {
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/IV2C28A.png');
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
overflow: hidden;
}

button {
display: block;
margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree-without-leaves">
<div class="tree-with-leaves">
</div>
</div>

<button>Click Me</button>
```